# Regex - substitute specific chars exept specific string

Tags: python, regex

I'm having hard time figuring out how to substitute every white space with `''`, exept thous that apear betweeen `" "`.

For example -

```
a = c + d;
```

is

```
a=c+d
```

and

```
foo ("hi bye",        "bye    hi");
```

is

```
foo("hi bye","bye    hi");
```

I have tried something like

```
re.sub('^(\"[^\"\n]*\")|\s|\\n', '', line)
```

but obviously that doesnt work.

Comment: Are there any nested quoted substrings that you need to account for? I suspect there can be also escaped double quotes inside `"...."`, right?

Comment: @michal you know https://regex101.com/, incl python interpreter

Comment: Are your requirements that you must use regex?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein No, but i do prefer using regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No "nested strings"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find:

```
r'(".*?")|(\s+)'
```

Replace:

```
r'\1'
```

---

The idea is to ignore all characters inside quotes, by first matching all quotes with something inside (`".*?"`) and replacing with the same (`\1`).

We know that the white spaces left (`\s+`) will not be inside quotes (or the first rule would have matched them instead) and replace these white spaces with nothing.

---

[See it in action](https://repl.it/Ekbv/2)

Comment: The `g`  should be removed.

Comment: i tried `re.sub('r"(\".*?\")|( +)"g', '$1', line)` on `line= let length = Keyboard.readInt("HOW MANY NUMBERS? ");`, but that didnt do anything..EDIT: printed `let$1length$1=$1Keyboard.readInt($1);`

Comment: @ndn - **\s+** would be better than ' +'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say in your comments that regex isn't required, I'm going to propose a novel concept: *don't use regex*.

Don't get me wrong.  I love regex.  It's an amazing powerful tool, and it can handle almost anything you ask of it, if you're willing to make a complicated enough expression.  There are times regex is the perfect tool, and cleans up dozens of lines of code in one simple expression.

But this is a simple task, dependent on one simple thing: you need a state of whether you're within a quote.

This code is so basic people may even say it's not pythonic.  But it works, and anyone can read it.

```python
def kill_spaces(test_str):
    inside_quote = False
    result = ""
    for character in test_str:
        if character != " " or inside_quote:
            result += character
        if character == '"':
            inside_quote = not inside_quote
    return result

test = 'foo ("hi bye",       "bye     hi");'
kill_spaces(test)
>>> 'foo("hi bye","bye     hi");'
```

Comment: I feel there's a more pythonic way of doing this (other than regex), but couldn't figure it out.  I'm open to suggestions.